# Oracle get substring before a space

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string with space in between, and I need to get the first string (it can be a number) before the space.

```
 WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT '123642134  10' AS quarter_cd FROM dual UNION ALL --VALID
)

 select *
  from test_data
 where regexp_like(quarter_cd, '', 'c')
```

The output should be:

```
123642134
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
Substr (quarter_cd, 1,instr(quarter_cd,' ') - 1)
```

Should do that.

Comment: @vivek you didn't specify you needed it as a regex. Why would you want regex.. Homework? Regexp_substr (quarter_cd, '^[^ ]+ ') Should do the same.

Comment: This is not a homework, i am new to oracle so was just obsessed to solve it via reg_ex !!! Working now, Thanks dude. It ll be great if you gave a little expalianation.!!!

Comment: @Vivek ok np. ^ is the start of the string but within square brackets ^ means "Not". so it says `^` start at the start of the string, `[^ ]` match NOT space. `+` means 1 or more times (so match 1 or more NON spaces). if you only wanted to match numbers, you could do '^[0-9]+' instead

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Rtrim(Substr('123642134  10',1,Instr('123642134  10',' '))) AS quarter_cd FROM dual;
```

Uses of string function used in upper query

- Instr()- to get position of any character or space from the given string.
- Substr()- to get substring from given string.
- Rtrim()- to remove spaces from right side.